# bare metal raid array with LVM dissapears after reboot

Tags: lvm, raid, mdadm, software-raid

### tl;dr:

RAID array + LVM dissapears after reboot.

### Detail

I wanted to set up an encrypted raid array, based on [this SO](https://superuser.com/a/1038421).

I set up a RAID array *"bare metal"* (i.e. on the disks not on the partitions). Once the array was built I didn't format it and ran `pvcreate`. Then I set up LVM and encryption in the usual way. (See [Digital Ocean Guide on RAID](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-debian-9), [arch guide on LVM on RAID](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM_on_software_RAID#LVM_installation).

After setting up encryption, I ran `mdadm --detail --scan | tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` then `update-initramfs -u`  and issued a reboot. `/dev/md0` is then gone. Where did I go wrong?

### Steps to debug.

There are a lot of similar questions, this is what I have tried so far based on my reading.

- Output of `mdadm --examine --scan` is blank.
- uncommented contents of `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`: `HOMEHOST <system>`, `MAILADDR root`, `ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=server:0 UUID=xxxxx` There are no duplicate entries as suggested in some SO answers.
- Issuing `service mdadm status` yields `Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit mdadm.service is masked.)`
- Issuing `cat /proc/mdstat` yeilds `Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] \n unused devices: <none>`
- I tried running `dpkg-reconfigure mdadm` and `update-initramfs -u` as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/411300/125254) and I did not get an option to enable "all". I tried rebooting after this, which also did not work.

As a last resort I tried `mdadm --assemble --scan`.

Strangely, the type is not `TYPE="linux_raid_member"` as I would have expected from [this SO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/319520/125254)

```
root@server:/home/user# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="xx" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="xx-xx"
/dev/sda5: UUID="xx" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="xx-xx"
/dev/mapper/server--vg-root: UUID="xx" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/server--vg-swap_1: UUID="xx" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sdb: PTUUID="xx" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sdc: PTUUID="xx" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sdd: PTUUID="xx" PTTYPE="gpt"
```

The array is over sd[bcd] and /dev/sda holds the root filesystem. This array drive is for data.

### Steps to recreate.

For completeness and in case it is useful.

- `mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd` Create array
- `pvcreate /dev/md0` Make physical volume
- `vgcreate data_group /dev/md0` Create vol group
- `lvcreate -n secure data_group -L +900G` Create volume
- `cryptsetup -v luksFormat /dev/data_group/secure` Setup encryption
- `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/data_group/secure cryptvault` Open encrypted volume
- `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/cryptvault` Partition
- `mkdir /mnt/vault` Make mount point
- `mount /dev/mapper/cryptvault /mnt/vault` Mount
- `mdadm --detail --scan | tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`Save array layout
- `update-initramfs -u` Update init with new config
- `reboot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is just a theory:** mdadm metadata version 1.2 is 4K from the start of the device and the disks already had existing GPT partition table on them when you created the array which was not removed by mdadm (I'd expect mdadm to remove all existing signatures, but that is the only explanation for the GPT signature existence). The array is now not assembled because for all tools (including mdadm) this just looks like and empty disk with GPT partition table (it is also possible that blkid detects the header backup near the end of the disk) not a mdmember, so the disks are ignored.

You can try to remove the partition table using `wipefs` -- first just plain `wipefs /dev/sdb` to detect and print all signatures and then `wipefs -o <offset>` with offset of the GPT signature printed by previous command. This might help the system to detect the disk as a mdmeber device.

If this doesn't help, I'd suggest starting over and picking metadata version 1.1 (`--metadata=1.1` option for mdadm, 1.1 places metadata at the start of the device) or creating the array on top of partitions (there is no benefit in using the disks without a partition table IMHO). Or of course you can wait for someone else with some better suggestions :-)

Btw. I assume this is a brand new setup so there are no valuable data on the devices, but it might be useful to backup first few MiBs of the disks before doing any irreversible changes.

Comment: The output of `/dev/sd[bcd]` was two `GPT` entries and one `PMBR` entry. Indeed I set up the GPT partition scheme prior to setting up mdadm. I'll start again with partitions, good to know there is no impact on performance.

Comment: Partitions worked. I also zeroed out the first 10000 sectors with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=10000` prior to setting up the partitions, to remove any unwanted metadata.